# Generar div en diferentes selecciones en Angular

Tags: html, angular

Contengo Una Validacion de Select Options lo que contengo es la siguiente validacion.

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="table1" *ngIf="selectOPT==1">
//contenido
</div>
```

Quisiera saber como duplicar el div ya que contengo un dropdown con múltiples opciones pero quiero mostrar el mismo div que contengo arriba al seleccionar alguna de ellas se muestren en todas mis selecciones dependiendo lo que no quiero es repetir codigo en cada 1 podrían ayudarme?

```
*ngIf="selectOPT==1 o selectOPT2 o SelectOPT3"
```

Comment: Quieres que el div actualice su valor dependiendo de la opción del select que se ha elegido?

Comment: No quiero que se duplique el mismo div digamos que si la seleccion es OPT2 se repita el div completo

Comment: He Cris, trata de usar las comas y puntos adecuadamente. No se entiende muy bien lo que estas preguntando

Answer (score -1):

Si tu lógica es compleja te recomendaría, en el archivo TS del componente, implementar una función que te retorne true o false y ahí implementar la lógica que necesites, de esta manera tendrías algo así:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="table1" *ngIf="mostrarDiv">
  //contenido
</div>
```

```js
    // Componente.component.ts
    public get mostrarDiv(): boolean {
      let result: boolean;
      // implementa aqui un switch o tu logica completa
      return result;
    }
```

Si esto no te vale, edita tu pregunta poniendo mas codigo si puedes.